# Add a div between rows in an unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to add a div (that spans across the page) in between list items in an unordered list?

For example, the image below shows a product listing page for an ecommerce site. Each product tile will be a list item in an unordered list. We want to put a break between 1 row of list items and add a div that spans the page. 
The added complication here too is that the tiles per row changes depending on the screen size and break points.
[image]

Comment: It's possible but will fail validation. Only `<li>`s are permitted as direct children of a `<ul>`. You don't have to use ul/li in the first place though.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but probably not all browsers will render it as expected, since is not a valid html.

You can just replace the list entirely with `div's` for better assurance...

Prove that it works:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

  <ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <div>This the between content</div>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>123</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this is just a proof snippet, but this does take into consideration that the number of columns could possibly change depending on browser width as stated in the last sentence of the question.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you need a solution that allows your rows to have a variable amount of items while still keeping the div firmly in place. If you're OK with your special `div` always being the second row, then there's a trivial CSS-only solution that involves flexbox and some absolute positioning.

- Wrap your list in a container that provides a new stacking context (`position: relative;`).
- Put your `ul` followed by your special `div` inside that container.
- Make your list into a flexible grid of blocks using flexbox and give your list-items a set height.
- Make some room for the `div` by giving your list's first child a bottom margin.
- Position the `div` with `absolute`, give it a height that fits nicely with the bottom margin you made, a top position fitting with the height of your list items (plus margins) and a 100% width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.with-static-row {
  position: relative;
  --margin: 0.5rem;
  --box: 10rem;
  --banner: 7rem; 
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul > :nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--banner) + var(--margin) * 3);
}

li {
  flex-basis: var(--box);
  height: var(--box);
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: var(--margin);
}

li, .static {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.static {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px dashed black;
  height: var(--banner);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--box) + var(--margin) * 3)
}
```

```html
<div class="with-static-row">
  <ul>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
    <li>&lt;li&gt;</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="static">&lt;div&gt;</div>  
</div>
```